# Java regex to parse a particular semicolon delimited param from a URL?

Tags: java, regex, string, parsing, url

I have a URL I'm expecting like:

```
www.somewebsite.com/misc-session/;session-id=1FSDSF2132FSADASD13213
```

I want to parse out

```
session-id=1FSDSF2132FSADASD13213
```

Using a regular express in Java, what would be the best approach to take for this?

Using a test regex website I've experimented with some different ways but I'm wondering what is the best approach that is the most fail safe, and protected incase the URL is actually formed like:

```
www.somewebsite.com/misc-session/;session-id=1FSDSF2132FSADASD13213?someExtraParam=false
```

or

```
www.somewebsite.com/misc-session/extra-path/;session-id=1FSDSF2132FSADASD13213?someExtraParam=false
```

I am always just looking for the value of "session-id".

EDIT:
The value of session-id is NOT limited to digits and is guaranteed to contain a combination of both.

Comment: Can you provide which expressions you've tried so we can previous attempts?

Comment: why not just `session-id=\d+`?

Comment: That is a strange path element you have here... But please, in the first place consider using `URI` to break your URI into components

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What is the best approach that is the most fail safe, and protected.

Well I think matching `word boundary` on both sides will be enough.

**Regex:** `\bsession-id=\d+\b`

**Note:-** Use `\\d` and `\\b` if regex flavor you are using needs double escaping.

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sR6oB7/1)**

---

Just in case `session-id` have characters in range `[A-Za-z0-9]` use this regex.

**Regex:** `\bsession-id=[A-Za-z0-9]+\b`

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sR6oB7/3)**

**[Ideone Demo](https://ideone.com/ajM9HN)**

Remember to include

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
```

Comment: I'm concerned the value of session-id isn't limited to digits, but I maybe wrong.

Comment: @JohnGiotta: I doubt that too, so make sure before procedding. If the `session-id` have `[A-Za-z]` too. You only need to add class. `[A-Za-z0-9]+` instead of `\d+`.

Comment: @JohnGiotta Yes the value is not limited to digits, and is guaranteed to contain a combination of both characters and digits. Please see edit above.

Comment: @AdamBronfin: I have already updated my answer keeping that in mind.

Comment: @noob, it doesn't work using your pattern and the code from Nikolases answer

Comment: @noob no match found on /app/session/info/;session-id=18HSKEI930128D244CC48B

Comment: @noob doing p.pattern() returns "session-id=[A-Za-z0-9]+". Is that valid? What do I need to pass to Pattern.compile()?

Comment: @noob I also tried \\b, didnt work. This is in java.

Comment: @AdamBronfin: Updated my answer along with demo.

Comment: @noob I tried exactly that with the double slash \\b and still didn't work. m.find() returned false.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107179/discussion-between-noob-and-adam-bronfin).

Answer (score 3):

Try this one:

```
String str = "www.somewebsite.com/misc-session/;session-id=213213213";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(session-id=\\d+)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);

if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(0));
}
```

Note that `session-id=` is always given and you are interested in the following number, that is represented with `\d` (use double `\\d` in Java). The `+` stands for at least one number at all.

However better look at the detailed description at [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/uW7mP8/1).

Comment: Don't know why you got down-voted. I guess show using the matcher as well?

Comment: Well, edited. But to be honest, do we use downvoting for an answer, that is good but should be more complex .. or for a bad answer at all? I'd choose the second way and leave a comment or better, edit it.